# Send Mail with button Error

Tags: ios, swift, email

I'm having an error with my code. I know there are a lot of tutorials on how to make a button send an email in swift, but I don't understand what's wrong with my code. Can someone help explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
import UIKit

import MessageUI

class AboutUsVC: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {

    }
    func configureMailController() -> MFMessageComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["Test@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("App - Help Contact")

        return mailComposerVC()

    }

    func showMailError() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry, couldn't send", message: "Sorry, we are having some troubles sending the message right now. :(", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        sendMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)

        self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result:  MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Have you tested your code using a real device? Also, be sure to check `canSendMail()` before presenting `MFMailComposeViewController`. Code: `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()`

Comment: @nathan Use `canSendMail` even before you attempt to create the composer.

Comment: I get the error on line 25 ("return mailComposerVC()").

Also I have the mail checking and all of that on the button that sends it. I just forgot to post it up there. 
Here is the link to my code ->
[link](https://pastebin.com/5pzCzq3E)

Comment: @nathan I forgot to tag you up there ^

Comment: Why are you confusing `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`? They are not the same thing. And [edit] your question (don't post comments) with the actual, complete, and exact error messages when you post a question about an error. And always point out the exact lines causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change below code

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMessageComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["Test@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("App - Help Contact")

        return mailComposerVC()

    }
```

with

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["contact.Studio228@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("In-Dose - Help Contact")

        return mailComposerVC

    }
```

Comment: Now on line 20 I get an error "Cannot assign value of type 'AboutUsVC' to type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?'"